# javascript won't show in grails 3.1.9

Tags: javascript, ajax, grails, gsp

Making the datepicker show via javascript but it doesn't work

```
<script>
    $( "#invoiceDate" ).datepicker({
        inline: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        onSelect: function(datetext){
        datetext = datetext+" 00:00:00.0"
        $('#invoiceDate').val(datetext);
        }
    });
    <script>
```

The code works in grails 3.0.9 but not in 3.1.9
And no other javascript functions work as well
My JS files are all in assets/javascripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in layouts main gsp, the javascript files must be defined via `<asset:src>`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to check your config because it seems that there isn't a valid jquery imported.

```
plugins {
 ...
 runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
 ...
}
```

Otherwise, check with Chrome (or firefox) inspector and i am quite sure that you have a lot of 404 for js resources. Check that urls and fix the path in your views.